# bash pattern question

Tags: bash, wildcards

I have files in a directory with file names which have digits, and some of them end with a 'd' character (not necessarily an extension). Here is an example set of files:

```
alle5m6ilsd.d
alle34mails
alle34mailsd
allemails
allemails.d
```

I want to write  UNIX bash command to select file names that have digits and end with a 'd'. So my answer should be:

```
alle5m6ilsd.d 
alle34mailsd
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the glob pattern:

```
*[[:digit:]]*d
```

- `*` matches zero or more characters
- `[:digit:]` matches any digit in your `locale`
- `d` matches literal `d`, at the end here

If you do not want to depend on your `locale`, for ASCII charset only:

```
*[0-9]*d
```

**Example:**

```
% ls               
alle34mails  alle34mailsd  alle5m6ilsd.d  allemails  allemails.d

% ls *[[:digit:]]*d
alle34mailsd  alle5m6ilsd.d
```

Answer (score 0):

Corrected pattern should be:

`*[[:digit:]].*d$`

or

`*[0-9].*d$`

Adding to the description from heemayl, only need to match a digit for that part of OP's requirements to be met. Then need to accept anynumber of other characters after the digit `.*`, which could include other digits. Then have to have a literal `d`, but it must be anchored to the end of the string `$`. The pattern from heemayl would fail to match both of the OP's examples and would falsely match anything with a `d` directly after the digits, not necessarily at the end, as per the OP's conditions.

Comment: These are regular expressions, not shell globbing patterns. Globbing patterns are automatically anchored.

Comment: Oops, correct, sorry, was in regex mode when I was reading this. Apologies to @heemayl. He gets my vote.